# Magento 1.9 with php7

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, php-7

i no that there are many issues regarding with it, but many of the solutions is not quite the same of mine. Im having problems installing magento 1.9. Im running php7, and when magento installation is in the download files section is giving me the error of:

```
Package community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.7: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.1.1
```

Basically because of my php version, i found many solutions like the extension available called "Inchoo_PHP7", but many of the solutions says to replace in the folder "app/...", but in my phase of "download" i dont even downloaded this files or dont exist, so it doesnt work, in my situation, how can i fix the php version when im in the download process of magento?

Comment: How did you set PHP to Version 7 in the first place?

Comment: It was already installed in my pc before i isntalled magento

Comment: Why not downgrade your PHP version?

Comment: Exactly. I switch between 5.6 and 7.1 when this problem occurs. Without knowing how your server is set up I can't help unfortunately

Comment: im using my local computer

Comment: Are you using MAMP? If so, you can switch PHP versions from the preferences

Comment: im not using wamp, everyhting was installed independently

Comment: Quite hard to say without knowing your server setup as per Mike's comment. You need to either install or switch to a lower version of PHP

Comment: download magento as zip package and extract - install - all ok

Comment: @Pedro did you succeed? I am tempting to start from https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/tree/1.9.4.x